# Reference.vb code debugging

Tags: vb.net

When adding a reference to a web service, a Reference.vb file gets generated to make all the service's types available to the hosting project.

When I put a breakpoint in that file it never gets hit. How can I solve this?

Comment: This [link](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/WSDebug.htm) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for why it never gets hit. Right now I don't know how to tell the Debugger to halt anyway, ignoring the Attribute but you should be able to remove the Attribute from Reference.vb and start your Debug session without VS regenerating the file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice there was the attribute on the class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VS2013 you can disable Just My Code in the debugging options.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346(v=vs.110).aspx

That will make VS ignore the DebuggerStepThroughAttribute that Stephan B mentions. If you're using older version of VS you can delete the attribute from the Reference.vb

Comment: Nice, I never looked for an option after 2008 ; )

Comment: Unfortunately I am using VS2010, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps;

1. Open the web service project and go to web services project's "My Project".
2. Go to ***Web tab***.
3. Choose "*Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application.*"
4. Choose "*Use Local IIS Web Server*"
5. Change Project URL: "http://localhost/YourWebService" to your service name.
6. Click on *"Create Virtual Directory*".
7. Set the breakpoint at desire location.

Debug Run the web services "F5".

Comment: The web service does not get called, the code to debug is in the referencing project.